# es6 meaning of double exclamation marks

Tags: javascript

in some es6 code I see following:

```
let layer_combined = layers.map(getLayer).filter(l => !!l);
```

what is the meaning of !! in the filter() return?

Comment: its short hand for converting a truthy/falsey value to a boolean true/false

Comment: Same as `.filter(Boolean)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a way of casting to a boolean with double negation.

A singular `!` negation produces a true/false value, but it's the opposite of what you want. Double negation produces a true/false value which matches the original intent.

Try it:

```
!!0 // false
!!1 // true
!!"test" // true
!!null // false
```

Comment: This question is a blatant duplicate from 9.5 years ago, less than a year after Stackoverflow started.  It should be closed as a duplicate, and not answered.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Answering a question twice in ten years should not be considered a problem.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty you're right its a duplicate. will close it. thanks for providing the link.

Comment: and thanks to @tadman !

Comment: @tadman sorry for one more on this. if l is an object let `l = 0 console.log(!!myobject);` one would use !! just to cast 0 to a boolean false, right? If it´s something like `l = {thanks: 'to tadman'}` it would be boolean true. If so I don't really see the need for this in given filter function.

Comment: @tadman *Any* duplicate is a problem.  Furthermore, this has been duplicated more than once, I just did due diligence and found the oldest one

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I strongly disagree. Duplicates are not a problem. "Closing as duplicate" is just an easy way to answer a question if it keeps getting asked over and over and over. If someone wants to take the time to answer a duplicate, let them. If nobody has the time, close as duplicate.

Comment: @tadman Disagree as much as you want, it just shows you don't know how StackOverflow is supposed to work